# Why are there additional objects in my render?

Tags: modeling, rendering

So I made a file with a few pipes in it, but here are even more in the render. Don´t know where they come from. Any ideas? Here´s the file https://www.dropbox.com/s/iu7xmyid2xrcbhi/thebatterie.blend?dl=0

[[image: solid view][1]]

[image: pipes render]

Answer (score 3):

You have arrays on your pipes, but they are disabled in the viewport so you don't see them.

[image]